# How to get html tag's inner html in js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example i have:

```
<p class="question"> 
this is my paragraph 
  <p> And i'm inside 
  tag in question class  
    <h1> And this is my heading</h1> 
  </p>
</p>
```

the question is how can i get inner html of question class like below:

```
this is my paragraph 
<p> And i'm inside tag in question class 
  <h1> And this is my heading</h1> 
</p>
```

Comment: Did you search for it?

Comment: searching for "jquery inner html" the first result is a full explanation page about what you just asked.

Searching for "js inner html" the first result is a full explanation page too. please search before asking a question

Comment: nested `p` tag may cause problem..... although `h1` inside `p` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 functions to get the inner html of an element

1. `.text()`
2. `.html()`

**.text()**

```
console.log($(".question").text());
```

`.text()` will give the innertext of the element but not tags

**.html()**

```
console.log($(".question").html());
```

`.html()` function this will give the inner tags also.

```
this is my paragraph <p> And i'm inside 
tag in question class <h1> And this is my heading
</h1> </p>
```

> In your case `.html()` would be fine

Comment: Or in vanilla JavaScript: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("question")[1].innerHTML);`

Comment: text will return only text not tags with html entities.

Comment: both print same result ("this is my paragraph")

Comment: I would really not jump into jQuery, the question asks  "js/jquery?", there are faster, mature native functions with good browser support that don't require jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[As per w3c docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) :

> A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.

Since your HTML contains `p` tag  within p which act as end tag and that `p` tag only contains that much text. The `</p>` doesn't have any role here since `p` tag is closed based on the documentation. Although the `p` tag permitted contents are [phrasing contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content).

---

You can use `div` instead of `p` tag to make it valid and get HTML content using **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property of dom element.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('.question').innerHTML
);
```

```html
<div class="question">
  this is my paragraph
  <div>And i'm inside tag in question class
    <h1> And this is my heading
</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(".question").text()
```

Or:

```
$(".question").html()
```

[Try it in JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rd4pu5p5/1/).

Comment: That should be `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not required.

You need the the Element.innerHTML function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

I would suggest using an ID instead of a class if there is only one instance on the page.

```js
myString = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting paragraph's is bad.

[**w3.org**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) **states :**

> The `<p>` element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including `<p>` itself).

So

```
console.log($('.question').html());
```

or

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].innerHTML);
```

would fetch only "**this is my paragraph**"

---

**Proposed Solution:**

Instead wrap your content in a `div` and then access the HTML. `innerHTML` can be accessed by various methods here are few of them.

1. [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) : `document.querySelector('.question').innerHTML`
2. [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) : `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0].innerHTML);`. **getElementsByClassName()** will return an array of matched elements so i used index to access the first elemnent.
3. [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) : `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML`

***Example:***

```js
var t = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
console.log(t[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="question">
  this is my paragraph
  <div>And i'm inside tag in question class
    <h1> And this is my heading</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #notme but to the novice it's not clear what document.getElementsByClassName("question")[1] would do, or why you would use a class selector if you only ever return the first matched selector.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you for giving me suggestion.
but i solved my problem just covered question class paragraph with a div tag like that

```
<div class="outer">
<p class="question"> 
this is my paragraph<p>hello world</p> <p> And i'm inside 
tag in question class <h1> And this is my heading
</h1> </p></p>
</div>
```

and by using 
   `$('.outer').html();`
it print all inside html.